# django apache mod-wsgi hangs on importing a python module from .so file

Tags: python, django, module, wsgi

I'm trying to deploy a django application for production on apache mod-wsgi. I have a third party python application called freecad which packages python module in an FreeCAD.so library file. Requests hang on 'import FreeCAD'. Some apache log errors tell me that it might be problem with zlib?? compression when trying to import this module.
Note that everything works just fine when using django's runserver.

After looking more into this, it's not a compression issue,neither is a permission.
I did as www-data user using

```
$ sudo -u www-data python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 16:22:56) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/usr/lib/freecad/lib')
>>> import FreeCAD
FreeCAD 0.10, Libs: 0.10R3225
>>>
```

but it still hangs on 'import FreeCAD' from web page request

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Set:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

See the application issues document on mod_wsgi wiki.

Most likely you have an extension module not designed to work in sub interpreter. The above forces it to run in main interpreter.

Comment: 'Thanks'*100 It works. I've spent most of the day trying to solve this. You saved me lot of frustration.

Comment: Oh my, been tearing my hair out with this for a day on a random hanging import.. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks a million. Saved my day!

Comment: You are the greatest! I don't even want to admit how long this issue had been plaguing my work.