# Flask WSGI application hangs when import transformers

Tags: flask, apache2, huggingface-transformers, wsgi

I am trying to deploy flask wsgi server. The problem starts when in my app.py file I do following import - `from transformers import MarianMTModel`, MarianTokenizer. This makes my server hang and I don't have clear understanding how to fix it. Here are my **app.py** content

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, session
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from transformers import MarianMTModel, MarianTokenizer

def create_app():
    # preinstall 
    app = Flask(__name__)
    CORS(app)
    return app

app = create_app()

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def main():
    return f'Server works!'
```

**apache.conf**:

```
WSGIPythonHome /home/ubuntu/venv/
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.co
    WSGIDaemonProcess app user=www-data group=www-data
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/MyApp/flask-app.wsgi

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/MyApp>
        WSGIProcessGroup app
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and **flask-app.wsgi**:

```
#!/home/ubuntu/venv/bin/python3.8
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/home/ubuntu/MyApp')

from app import app as application
```

Btw, application works perfectly locally.

Could you share possible solutions for this problem if you run by chance same. Thank you in advance!

I tried same approach like [here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13895889/flask-wsgi-application-hangs-when-import-nltk](https://stackoverflow.com) But seems didn't help much

Comment: Actually, adding WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} line outside virtual host helped to solve this issue.