# OpenCV 3.2 hangs on cv2.cvtColor

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, mod-wsgi, wsgi, opencv3.1

I have a set of web APIs that I run on Apache with WSGI for image processing.
Recently I upgraded my OpenCV to 3.2 (I'm using Python 2.7)
OpenCV seems to work fine when I run it from console, but when I make web API calls openCV hangs on converting image to grayscale:

```
cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

It's totally random, couldn't find a pattern. Some times it hangs and some times it works for the same image.
Any ideas?

More Info:
When I do it from shell command all works fine:

```
>>> sudo python manage.py shell
>>> import cv2
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> image = Image.open(img_path)
>>> image = np.asarray(image)
>>> print image
    array([[[255, 255, 255],
            [255, 255, 255],
            [255, 255, 255],...]]], dtype=uint8)
>>> img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
>>> print img
    array([[255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       ..., 
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8)
```

UPDATE:
The issue is with WSGI. When I specify more than 1 process in apache config for WSGIDaemonProcess I can easily reproduce the hangs. After setting it to 1 it works

```
WSGIDaemonProcess processes=1 threads=25 maximum-requests=100
```

I'm still not sure why multiple processes in wsgi cause troubles

Comment: Have you inspected the image sizes when it hangs?

Comment: @ilke444 
the one that I found hanging consistently is 852x852. Here it is: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_eaJCfhUFmFWmdJQzhKVGJNbDQ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV imread hanging when called from a web request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315043/opencv-imread-hanging-when-called-from-a-web-request)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and found a fix -> just add to your apache configuration:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

Apparently it happens when you have an extension module not designed to work in sub interpreter. The above forces it to run in main interpreter.

Sources:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#python-simplified-gil-state-api
- [django apache mod-wsgi hangs on importing a python module from .so file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236045/django-apache-mod-wsgi-hangs-on-importing-a-python-module-from-so-file)
- http://blog.rtwilson.com/how-to-fix-flask-wsgi-webapp-hanging-when-importing-a-module-such-as-numpy-or-matplotlib/